# spring mvc 3.1 login and session bean sharing difficulty

Tags: session, spring-mvc, authentication

After the user logged in from a browser A,

browser B loads the same userBean as browser A, so browser B is automatically logged in.

I would like to keep using HandlerInterceptorAdapter instead of spring security.

What is fix it?

Thanks in advance. Here is the code,

**LoginInterceptor**

```
public class LoginInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserBean userBean;

    public boolean preHandle(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Object handler) throws Exception {

        String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        Boolean matched = requestURI.contains(contextPath + "/login");
        if (matched || userBean.getLogined()) {
            return true;
        } else {            
            response.sendRedirect(contextPath + "/login");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("login")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private UserBean userBean;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginGET(Model model) {
        LoginInput loginInput = new LoginInput();
        model.addAttribute("login", loginInput);
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginPOST(@Valid LoginInput loginInput, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "login";
        }       
        Boolean logined = userBean.login(loginInput.getUserName(), loginInput.getPassword());
        if (!logined) {
            result.rejectValue("userName", "IncorrectLogin", "Incorrect login or password!");
            return "login";
        }       
        return "redirect:/index";
    }
}
```

**LoginInput**

```
public class LoginInput {
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private String userName;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Password must not be blank.")
    @Size(min = 4, max = 20, message = "Password must between 4 to 20 Characters.")
    private String password;

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
            return password;
    }
```

**AppConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean @Scope("singleton")
    public LdapService ldapService() throws LDAPException {
        return new LdapService();
    }

    @Bean @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public UserBean userBean() {
        return new UserBean();
    }

    @Bean @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public UserConfig userConfig() {
        return new UserConfig();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this cannot work. Your `UserBean`
 objects are session-scoped. So when a user uses a different browser, they will have a new session created (and a different UserBean)